# Read column values to variable in SSIS using for each loop

Tags: sql, loops, ssis, for-loop, each

I want to read the resultset of a table using the following stmt:

```
Select col1 as A,col2 as B from tablename;
```

Then, I want to read each row of the result set into local variables of the SSIS package and for each row I have to pass the values to the script task.

I want to use `foreach` loop in SSIS. I took Foreach Item Enumerator.

The question: How to read the values into the variable using the For each Item enumerator and how can i iterator can i use `select count(*) from table`; pass that value to a variable and asssign the count value in the foreach loop.

I'm stuck at how to assign the count value and read columns to variables. Can anyone help with these?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's a "stmt"? I pronounce that "stumped", but that can't be right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what it is that you're trying to do, but it would seem that you're trying to process data in your control flow.  The foreach iterator is not made for processing data sets, it's made for iterating over multiple data sets and doing something to each of them, usually passing them to a data flow.

You might find it more useful to create a data flow.  Start with a data source component that gets the data that you want and then pass the data to a Script Component to do the processing.